# Load external js file, modify something in it then execute it normally

Tags: javascript

I want to 1) load an external js file programmatically via js code, 2) replace some **literal** values in it and only that 3) execute it normally.

Namely, instead of this single step

```
<script async src="https://external_domain1.com/script1.js"></script>
```

I want something to do 3 steps:

```
<script>
  // incomplete solution
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://external_domain1.com/script1.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script); // must not be executed at this point yet
  //?????
</script>
```

How to do that?

Comment: download it using XMLHttpRequest/Fetch, modify the response text, add it in an inline script

Comment: This is pretty dubious, to be honest, there's a reason this isn't really done - its unsafe and you could be loading _any_ code right into your website that way... If its an API, it should provide appropriate calls to do this, otherwise you have to replace using `Regex`, and you c an never be 100% certain this keeps working.

Comment: I think you can do it..but you don't have to do this. because of security reasons

Comment: @Bravo right. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ParthRaval I'm not asking  your opinion regarding security

Comment: @tajara - better way? sure. Use **your** server to request the script, make the changes on the server ... then you just need to `<script async src="url to script on your server">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the script using fetch/XMLHttpRequest, then modify the text in the response, then add it as an inlilne script

```
fetch("https://external_domain1.com/script1.js")
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  const s = text.replace('foo', 'bar');
  script.textContent = s;
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});
```

No need for async flag here, and just append it to the `document.body`

---

> Alternative

Have some resource on your *server* which, when accessed does the following

- reads `https://external_domain1.com/script1.js`
- modifies the content
- sends the modified content as the response

lets assume this script is written in PHP, lives in the folder `/path-to-script` and is called `magicScript.php` - then in HTML you'd just have

```
<script async src="/path-to-script/magicScript.php">
```

Comment: will all of that work well, as if a file was loaded normaly via "script src ... async ..." ?

Comment: of course you don't do async flag ... inline script don't do that